# Sortable, auto create new list when placed in between two lists

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

So I came to the point where I really can't find anything online on how to solve this. I'm using a jQuery Sortable function like this:

```
<div class="sortable">
    <div class="item" id="1"></div>
    <div class="item" id="2"></div>
</div>
<div class="sortable">
    <div class="item" id="3"></div>
    <div class="item" id="4"></div>
    <div class="item" id="5"></div>
</div>
```

Now, what I want to get is another "sortable"-div when the item is dragged in between of the two sortable div's. Their is a margin of 10 px inbetween them which I think has to be replaced by a div of 10px width, so I tried..

I created a div inbetween, sortable also but with the width of the 10px margin. This thing doesn't work, just because when an item is dragged in there is no div anymore in between those and it'll just be possible to do it once.

Here's a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/p5Z3s/5/

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I don't need code, just someone to point me out where to start and maybe how to solve this.

### Example:

**When an item is dragged like this:**

[image: example1]

**It should result in placing it in between, something like this:**

[image: example2]

[image: example3]

---

### UPDATE 1:

I just tried to create the spacing with a new sortable div, check out the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/p5Z3s/6/

BUT, now the problem is, the update function is not called, which is needed for saving the positions. Also, as soon as I dragged it in between of two columns, I add the needed spacing again with:

```
$(this).before( "<div class=\"dropable gallery__item sortable\"></div>" );
$(this).after( "<div class=\"dropable gallery__item sortable\"></div>" );
```

They are created succesfully, but it is not possible anymore to drag an item inside of one.

I tried to update and refresh them by using:

```
$( ".sortable" ).sortable('refresh').trigger('update');
```

But it fails with this error:

> Error: cannot call methods on sortable prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'

---

### UPDATE 2:

Problem of the

```
$( ".sortable" ).sortable('refresh').trigger('update');
```

solved. Only thing that's not working right now is the:

```
$(this).before( "<div class=\"dropable gallery__item sortable\"></div>" );
$(this).after( "<div class=\"dropable gallery__item sortable\"></div>" );
```

The div's are created, but don't allow sortable items to be placed inside.

Comment: What are the steps to reproduce the issue? (In your fiddle)

Comment: @Trevor as you can read in my question I'm looking for a solution to dynamicly add an "sortable" class div inbetween the two when an item is dragged inbetween.

Comment: Can you tell me in the example fiddle, where you want to drag the pants to make the new sortable?

Comment: @IrvinDomininakaEdward in between of the shirt and top!

Comment: @IrvinDomininakaEdward I've added some example pics

Comment: @JoranDenHouting are you looking for this? http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/4SG4f/ I think there are some aspect to fix but seems to be ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key point is :

- call `.sortable()` on newly created divs (I imagine you figured out this much ...),
- call [`.sortable('refresh')`](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-refresh) on the existing ones, to make them aware of the new guys.

---

You can add empty divs between your columns, and use [`.droppable()`](http://jqueryui.com/droppable) :

```
<div class="sortable">
    <div class="item" id="1"></div>
    <div class="item" id="2"></div>
</div>
<div class="droppable">
</div>
<div class="sortable">
    <div class="item" id="3"></div>
    <div class="item" id="4"></div>
    <div class="item" id="5"></div>
</div>

$('.droppable').droppable({
    accept: ".item",
    drop: function(e, ui) {
       //insert a new sortable list in the dom
       //stick the item inside this list
       //update the setup :
       // - $(new list).sortable(...);
       //     make the existing lists aware of the new list :
       // - $(all sortables).sortable('refresh');
    }
});
```

See [this sortable example](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists-through-tabs) (interaction with a droppable), and the documentation for [droppable](http://jqueryui.com/droppable)

---

You could do a similar thing using only `sortable`s, as you did :

- in base html, or in javascript setup, insert an empty sortable div between each pair of starting div,
- every time an item is dropped, check the resultaing layout, and fix up the alternance `non-empty`/`empty`/`non-empty`/...  ,
- don't forget to call `.sortable()` on newly created divs, and `.sortable('refresh')` on the existing ones.

---

FWIW, I find it clearer to separate the two roles `existing, sortable list` / `empty droppable placeholder`

Comment: Thank you very much for the efford. I tried both ways but got stuck.. See the update in my question, I added a new fiddle and described the problem I'm facing. I used the `.sortable()` on the "spacing"-div's.

Comment: Don't forget to run `.sortable({...options...})` on the newly created divs. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LeGEC/DKzS4/3/). I'm doing it with a droppable, but you can adapt it to a sortable.

Comment: Thank you very much LeGEC! You just made my day, everything is working now :)

Comment: Also, don't forget to set `dropOnEmpty` to true in your sortable!

Answer (score 0):

jqueryUI sortable does not implement this functionality

You should have a look to [empty lists](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/#empty-lists) option and upgrade `sortable` to detect cases when need to dynamically create/remove empty lists between your lists

Also you can google for **swappable** implementations, it might be helpful for your task.

Comment: The grid isn't an option as we want to use it the way it is: Creating your own outfit. So, they can be dragged everywhere they want, and we would like to auto create a new column inbetween when an item is dragged in there.

Comment: You misunderstood.. It's far from what we are looking for, a grid takes away all the flexibility of creating an outfit.

Comment: not start from grid, start from empty lists example, and teach it to create empty lists(and bind sortable to it) when this needed

Answer (score -1):

Have you had a look at the portlets? It looks like it would work for you.

http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#portlets

I haven't looked too far into it but it looks like you can actually define a grid layout for your divs.

If this doesn't work then I'm most probably misunderstood your question.

Comment: Portlets is almost the same as we are using right now, it's doesn't have auto-column creation too and we'll still not be able to drag items in between of two columns.

Comment: @JoranDenHouting I'm not an expert with jQuery and how it works but on the drop event, check if the position is in the gutter and if it is, move the other ones to the right/left accordingly.

Comment: this should be a comment, since it's not an answer and doesn't directly solve the problem.